# Error deploying AWS Cloudformation LogGroup but it still creates resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-cloudformation

I've been setting up AWS ECS Clusters and Services and needed to add logs to the CloudFormation.

When-ever I deploy the following (StackName is a parameter submitted as `testxyzdailyprocessor5`

```
Resources:
  ECSLogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties: 
      LogGroupName: !Sub ${StackName}-ecslogs
      RetentionInDays: 3
```

it generates an error event that i've retrieved using event['message']

```
Stack creation initiated. Stack ID: arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:501550104875:stack/testxyzdailyprocessor5/b621a810-2aaa-11ee-963d-02ad92224953
Error deploying CloudFormation template: An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the DescribeLogStreams operation: 1 validation error detected: Value '/aws/cloudformation/arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:501550104875:stack/testxyzdailyprocessor5/b621a810-2aaa-11ee-963d-02ad92224953' at 'logGroupName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\.\-_/#A-Za-z0-9]+
```

however the log group is created successfully!

1. why is there an error but it creates ok
2. where is it getting the name which is the full stack arn name ( `/aws/cloudformation/arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:501550104875:stack/testxyzdailyprocessor5/b621a810-2aaa-11ee-963d-02ad92224953` when i am specifying defining the name abased on the `${StackName}-ecslogs` ?

i have put this resource log into a standalone file and it creats without any errors!
what could i be doing in the further file to udpate that value. its definitely not deliberate

Wondering if someone else has seen/experienced?  (full template file here: https://pastebin.com/02Z1NuUS )

Comment: I think it's implicitly created by the ECS container

Comment: I know I have experienced an issue with cloudformation validation being stricter than actual resource name validation requires. Could be an example of that. I would check for trailing or leading whitespace-characters and try with a shorter and simpler StackName value. Then I would try changing the parametername to something else. It seems it may be a substitution error when parsing the ${StackName}.

Answer (score -1):

This is correct behaviour because the log group doesn't have the property `DeletionPolicy` set to `Delete`. The default is `Retain`. Cloudformation doesn't roll back the stack until after the log group has been created, thus it is there after rollback.

The companion property of `UpdateReplacePolicy` should also be set for log groups. This governs behaviour when it is updated or replaced, which is usually the same as when it is deleted.

When developing a template it is a very good idea to have these set to `Delete`, or you will get the exact issues you are having.

And it is a good habit to ALWAYS set these two for log groups, and most resources that support them.

More in depth explanation in the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html

Comment: I don't think this is what OP was asking about... The issue is that Log Group is created even though CloudFormation says it wasn't.

Comment: That is true. Thank my scatterbrain for not reading the question properly. My apologies!